# Set custom emptyView CardWithList

Tags: android, cardslib

I'm trying to set a custom `EmptyView`.

Using:

```
@Override
protected void initCard(){
    View empty view = getView() //inflate the empty view, bind views and return
    setEmptyView(view);
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` because the LinerListView is not yet instantiated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.prototypes.LinearListView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.prototypes.CardWithList.updateEmptyStatus(CardWithList.java:656)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.prototypes.CardWithList.setEmptyView(CardWithList.java:631)
```

When trying to set the emptyView after running `myCard.init()` then i'm getting the default *EmptyView*:

```
myCard.init();
myCardView.setCard(myCard);
myCard.setEmptyView(myEmptyView);
```

Any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug to be fixed.

In any case it is the way to customize your EmptyView:

```
@Override
protected void initCard() {

     //....

     //Provide a custom view for the ViewStud EmptyView         
    setEmptyViewViewStubLayoutId(R.layout.my_view);

}
```

You can check:

- [How to customize the Empty View](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDWITHLIST.md#how-to-customize-the-empty-view)
- [Example in demo sample](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/demo/extras/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/demo/extras/cards/WeatherCard.java#L90)